# How do I use magenta.js and p5.js both?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to write source code that can draw images and play music which is related to the drawing image. So I use magenta and p5 both. But when I press the button that generate musics, there comes an error like this.

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is not a function
    at tf-core.esm.js:17:1
    at tf-core.esm.js:17:1
    at t.scopedRun (tf-core.esm.js:17:1)
    at t.tidy (tf-core.esm.js:17:1)
    at f (tf-core.esm.js:17:1)
    at tf-core.esm.js:17:1
    at t.scopedRun (tf-core.esm.js:17:1)
    at t.runKernelFunc (tf-core.esm.js:17:1)
    at t.runKernel (tf-core.esm.js:17:1)
    at oneHot_ (one_hot.ts:58:1)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.